# Redirect SSTP traffic from Ubuntu Apache2 server to internal Windows Server

Tags: windows, vpn, ubuntu-16.04, sstp

So this weekend i have been working on migrating my `apache2` server to a `docker` container which i have no issues with.

I currently have a windows server with `SSTP` and Exchange 2016 both using port `443` for traffic.

The idea is to have incoming `443` traffic to be forwarded to my ubuntu server and apache will decide based on the aliases i gave the virtual hosts, where the user will be redirected to. This i have working BUT what if a user is trying to connect to the VPN that also uses port 443? How would i be able to redirect that traffic to my server?

What i had thought was to create a rule for `IPTABLES` to have the destination be `vpn.domain.com` and forward it to the server but since all subdomains/CNames are just aliases leading to the same host (my external IP), therefore all requests on port `443` will just be sent to the windows server bypassing my webhost which is not what i want.

What i also actually tried was to use apache to forward any incoming connections on `443` via `ServerAlias vpn.domain.com` to the windows server since its on `443` but that did not work.

Im not sure how i can go about this and im thinking i would just need to create a new VPN service on my ubuntu server afterall. If there is any way i can achieve what i need, that would save me the hassle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with `SSLH`

Install SSLH

`SSLH` is packaged for most Linux distributions, so you can install it using the default package managers.

```
sudo apt install sslh
```

Configure Apache

As you already know, Apache will listen on all network interfaces (i.e 0.0.0.0:443) by default. We need to change this setting to tell the webserver to listen on the localhost interface only (i.e 127.0.0.1:443 or localhost:443).

To do so, edit the webserver (nginx or apache) configuration file and find the following line:

```
 listen 443 ssl;
```

And, change it to:

```
listen 127.0.0.1:443 ssl;
```

If you’re using Virutalhosts in Apache, make sure you have changed that it too.

```
VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443
```

Save and close the config files. Do not restart the services.

Configure SSLH

Once you have made the webservers to listen on local interface only, edit SSLH config file:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/sslh
```

Find the following line:

```
Run=no
```

And, change it to:

```
Run=yes
```

Then, scroll a little bit down and modify the following line to allow SSLH to listen on port 443 on all available interfaces (Eg. 0.0.0.0:443).

```
DAEMON_OPTS="--user sslh --listen 0.0.0.0:443 --ssh 127.0.0.1:22 --ssl 127.0.0.1:443 --openvpn 127.0.0.1:1194 --pidfile /var/run/sslh/sslh.pid"
```

Where,

- user sslh : Requires to run under this specified username.
- listen 0.0.0.0:443 : SSLH is listening on port 443 on all available interfaces.
- sshs 127.0.0.1:22 : Route SSH traffic to port 22 on the localhost.
- ssl 127.0.0.1:443 : Route HTTPS/SSL traffic to port 443 on the localhost.
- openvpn 127.0.0.1:1194 : Route openvpn traffic to port 1194 on the localhost

Save and close the file.

Finally, enable and start `sslh` service to update the changes.

```
sudo systemctl enable sslh

sudo systemctl start sslh
```

Change ip, port and protocols to accomplish your needs.

Comment: Intriguing. I'll have to give this a try later. Thanks!